# Yellow discoloration in Avocado leaves

Tags: leaves, avocado

Our two-year-old avocados have started flowering. But I recently noticed yellow patches on the leaves of the flowering plants. The leaves on the non-flowering plants seem to be fine. Otherwise, the plants are well irrigated and fertilized.

Would be grateful for help with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that these are planted outdoors?  What part of the world?  Are  you a commercial farm?